# interaction with windows in java

Tags: java, windows

I currently want to build a simple application using java or python.
I started coding not long ago, I do not know where to start from.
these are things I would like to know :

1. basically I want to build a background application(or program) that detects current keyboard layout(as in, which language), and just displays the next language on the screen everytime I push shift + alt so that I can know to which language I am switching in windows 10.(because task bar is now set to automatically be hidden when mouse cursor is not around it. and I speak russian, korean english and spanish, I need to know which language I am currently using in keyboard, but with the hidden task bar, it is inconvenient)
2. considering 1, how do I make java detect the language within windows system?
   I think I need to learn how to study programs or system in order to build anything, I do not require direct answer to this question.
   I want to understand the design process in java(or any language), and this is a part of study pertaining to this.
   so in lieu of direct answer, I would like to read sources or books.

thanks for reading!

Comment: Right click on the taskbar, choose Settings and switch Automatically hide the taskbar in desktop mode to Off.

Comment: I intentionally set the taskbar in this way. I do not want to switch that option.